# Can't get element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My .XML database looks like:

```
<root>
    <Lemma>
        <Lemma.LemmaSign>cat</Lemma.LemmaSign> 
        <Lemma.PartOfSpeech>(noun)</Lemma.PartOfSpeech> 
        <Lemma.UsageLabel>(kt)</Lemma.UsageLabel>
        <Sense>
            <TE>
                <TE.TE> animal</TE.TE>
            </TE>
            <Pronunciation>/ 
                <Pronunciation.Pronunciation>[coot]</Pronunciation.Pronunciation>/
            </Pronunciation>
            :
            <Example>
                <Example.Example> it's a cat</Example.Example>
                <Example.Translation> it's animal</Example.Translation>
                |
            </Example>
        </Sense>
    </Lemma>
</root>
```

and that's my code:

```
var elements = XElement.Load("objects.xml");
var query1 = from query in elements.Descendants("Lemma")
            let null_LemmaSign = query.Element("Lemma.LemmaSign")
            let null_TE = query.Element("TE.TE")
            where wyszuk == query.Element("Lemma.LemmaSign").Value
            select new
            {
              word = null_LemmaSign == null ? "none" : null_LemmaSign.Value,
              te = null_TE == null ? "none" : null_TE.Value,
            };

foreach (var e in query1)
{
 MessageBox.Show(e.word.ToString() + " - " + e.te.ToString());
}
```

And the problem is that output looks like:
cat - none
and should be 
cat - animal

how to get TE.TE from my .xml?

Comment: @jimmy_keen: Good suggestion. I would use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` since the OP then checks for `null_TE == null`, meaning they expect cases where the element will not be found.

Comment: @Douglas: yep that's probably best bet here. Removed comment since you already included all I had to say in your answer.

Comment: @Douglas I've question again - how to get more elements: <TE><TE.TE> cat</TE.TE></TE>,<TE><TE.TE> cat2</TE.TE></TE>,<TE><TE.TE> cat3</TE.TE></TE> - now I can get only 1st element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assumes that `<TE.TE>` is a direct child of `<Lemma>`, which it is not. Rather, `<TE.TE>` is a child of `<TE>`, which is a child of `<Sense>`, which is a child of `<Lemma>`. Your code should be adapted like so:

```
let null_TE = query.Element("Sense").Element("TE").Element("TE.TE")
```

For simplicity, you could, as jimmy_keen suggests, use `Descendants`:

```
let null_TE = query.Descendants("TE.TE").FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Hi there again,
I used it, but I noticed that I got more elements of TE.TE 
[<TE><TE.TE> cat</TE.TE></TE>,<TE><TE.TE> cat2</TE.TE></TE>,<TE><TE.TE> cat3</TE.TE></TE>:]

How to get not only first, but 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: Remove the `FirstOrDefault`, and loop through your sequence: `foreach (var te in query.Descendants("TE.TE"))`